# Is this a scraper site, or what?

Tags: discussion, mathoverflow

What is up with this site: https://mathoverflow.net/ ? Is it a clone or something? I wasn't paying attention and went to login, and it says that my name is unknown... What's up? I revoked access from my Google account just to be sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/41/differences-between-mathoverflow-and-math-stackexchange

Answer (score 16, accepted):

-overflow and -stackexchange are sister sites, mathoverflow specifically is research-level math-oriented, while math.stackexchange is open to questions of all levels (thanks Arturo).

Comment: I would not call it "less serious", but rather "open to questions at all levels." I for one take it seriously.

Comment: Ah! Is there a reason why it said I was unknown when I linked my Google OpenId? I've never had that problem on any Stack sites.

Comment: Thanks Arturo, fixed it. Josh, that could be because its an overflow site and not a stack site, I am not sure how cross-linking works with those.

Comment: MathOverflow and math.stackexchange are "sister sites" in the sense that there are a number of users who are active on both sites, but on a technical level, the software running them is completely independent. @Josh: MathOverflow is not part of the Stack Exchange 2.0 network, so it doesn't know about your login. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange_Network#StackExchange_1.0 for a little bit of history on how this came about.

Comment: And also note that the fact MathOverflow runs on StackExchange 1.0 is one indication of the fact that it actually pre-dates Math.StackExchange (which only came about after the SE2 platform). So no, it certainly is not a clone.

Answer (score 11):

That site runs on the Stack Exchange 1.0 platform.

These sites run on the Stack Exchange 2.0 platform.

For more detail and context see:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/