# mathoverflow.net? Is it part of stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this a scraper site, or what?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1533/is-this-a-scraper-site-or-what)

It appears that it is a really old version of math.stackexchange.com

Why does it still exist, if it was or is a part of stackexchange?

Comment: See here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533/is-this-a-scraper-site-or-what

Comment: Dear alexy13, I've closed this question as an exact duplicate; please see the question linked above.

Comment: In addition to that, the FAQs both on the main site here *and* on MathOverflow should've made plenty clear that the two sites are distinct entities serving different purposes. Oh wait, users don't read FAQs. -grumble grumble-

Comment: @willie some users don't read *anything*. Even the pop-up dynamic help on answers we added for new users :(

Comment: @willie still, I would like to thank alexy for asking on meta -- that is definitely a step in the right direction and I always applaud users who find and make use of the meta site. :)